# Merging two pre-sorted lists with different lengths?

Tags: python, sorting

How do I merge two sorted lists with different lengths into one? The two lists are presorted, but i need to make sure they are still sorted after I put them together.  I'm trying to fix my code, but using strictly what I have currently. No heap/sort/merge/zip, dictionaries etc.

EDIT: I am trying to append the items to an entirely new list. The end result should be
new_list = [0, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9]

My current program skips out of the remaining 9 in numbers2. If I switch the "and" to "or", the index goes out of range.

I've looked at other questions similar to this, but all the answers involve using other built in sorting methods, which I am trying to avoid.

```
def sort_numbers(list1, list2):
    new_list = []
    list1_index = 0
    list2_index = 0

    while list1_index != len(list1) and list2_index != len(list2):
        if list1[list1_index] < list2[list2_index]:
            new_list.append(list1[list1_index])
            list1_index += 1
        else:
            new_list.append(list2[list2_index])
            list2_index += 1
    return new_list


def main():
    numbers1 = [1, 3, 5, 5]
    numbers2 = [0, 1, 9, 9, 9]
    sorted_numbers = sort_numbers(numbers1, numbers2)
    print(sorted_numbers)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Are you looking to *merge* them, or *append* one list to the other? If you're looking to merge them, I would just write `sorted_numbers = list(sorted(numbers1 + numbers2))`.

Comment: Sorry I meant compare the values at their indexes, and append them to an entirely new list

Comment: new_list = [0, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 9, 9, 9]

Comment: The code I suggested in my first comment does produce your desired output.

Comment: When your while loop finished, you still have left over items in one list. You need to test for this and extend. Something like: `if list2_index < len(list2):` `new_list.extend(list2[list2_index:])`. Because of the way slices work in python, you don't even need the `if`, you can just add the remaining slices and one will be empty.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using list()

Comment: Then just don't use it. It was 100% pointless in the code that @larsks posted.

Comment: Thanks Kelly! At the time I posted I couldn't remember if `sorted` return a list or an iterator.

Comment: @larsks Hmm, I guess it *could* return an iterator, but I don't see how it could be done *efficiently*. I don't see a way it could take linearithmic time and *less* than linear space, so an iterator couldn't have much of a benefit.  `heapq.merge` does return an iterator, but that's for a different input. (But it's ruled out by the question just like `sorted`.)

Comment: @larsks Wait... I was thinking of complete sorts. If the iterator were only partially consumed, it could have an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

You should just change that `return` statement to:

```
return new_list + list1[list1_index:] + list2[list2_index:]
```

At that moment there might be one of the two lists that still has values at (and after) their corresponding index, which should all be appended to the part that was already merged. One of the two extra terms will be an empty list (slice), but that doesn't matter. It is the other term that is important (whichever of the two it happens to be).

Comment: does the [index:] just mean from the current index to the very last? The : is the slicing notation?

Comment: While this does solve the problem at hand, it comes with the overhead of maintaining two extra counter variables which are not necessary.

Comment: @Cocopun, yes, it is like that.

Answer (score 0):

Since your lists are already sorted, you can build something that compares only the first values in the list, and pops out the lower value until one of the lists is empty. All the elements of the list which is not empty then can simply be added to the end of the new list.

```py
def sort_numbers(list1, list2):
    new_list = []
    
    while len(list1) > 0 and len(list2) > 0:
        if list1[0] <= list2[0]:
            new_list.append(list1.pop(0))
        else:
            new_list.append(list2.pop(0))
        
    return new_list + list1 + list2
```

Comment: `pop(0)` destroys the time complexity of the algorithm. It changes from O(n) to O(n²).

Comment: Ah, that is new information to me. How does `list1 = list1[1:]` compare?

Comment: I love this, thank you! As a new python learner, this solution amazed me a lot!

Comment: @xprilion, slicing has the same issue. Destroys the good time complexity.

Comment: @CocoPun If quadratic time can still amaze you, check [this](https://tio.run/##VY/RCoMgFIbve4pDV7ZJ1GKwDXqSEQdHRkKamLF6eqdZY5NzIXzH///Uq@1HVd20ca7lHUyjsahm@eJmIqcleyTgzwo1PJvt@u7FwIENAzngtpAzrblqiRTKg1yPmhRZtnHD7WyUzziDZIunSZKEKsn87p6xN5ahp6RQUbj6aX7ZJbCCgsf3OBEHY94ezn7p7wtHMP3GRClthLLk/20QEx0gKiY5ItQ1pIhBEzGNntHZuQ8) out.

Comment: @CocoPun Or [this](https://tio.run/##VY7LCoMwEEX3fsXFVVJC0UqhLfglIoPFSF3kQYyQfr2NjZYaZhHmzj0c@/Yvo6ubdcvSywGTcZ70rJ7STewU@CNDfE762Wk0TI2aBQ7joLoQf/xsjWUFxxBXhFFjmhULAk3L2yzLVqTqYmkDbeQSNZpSoBK4xmn/s8uaFQIxvqdJ8Wom@90tHh1Ud7D4Yfi3Zd2oPTt2eRQbBxDpTkki1DVyolWTKE@eyXlZPg).